# How to reset or change behaviour of mouse cursor in impoly/imroi

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have question concerning reset of interactive behavior of mouse.
When I click on button and activate  mouse to create a ROI on the image
But user did it by mistake and want to select different option and click on listbox and then on button ROI. 
How can I reset ( option impoly with cross like this; +)?

I would appreciate any help or advice.

Comment: just let him choose a mistake one, then he will can select the other option from listbox and choose again with imroi, and run over the previous mistaken choose.

Comment: "But user did it by mistake..." The typical way to clear a special mouse function is to either look for the escape key or when clicking outside of the interesting (figure) area.